# Cocoa menu with images

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, image, menu

I need to make a popup or pull down menu in Cocoa that will contain either an image or an image with text as the representation of the item.  Can anyone suggest a way I could do this programatically?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Any sort of menu in Cocoa, whether it's in the menubar, part of an `NSPopUpButton`, or a combobox, uses `NSMenu` to display its menu.  The `NSMenu` displays a list of `NSMenuItem`s.  Each `NSMenuItem` has a `-[NSMenuItem setImage:]` method.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Wow, I had actually just made a popup menu so this was quite trivial once I knew that I could just set the image like that, thanks!

Comment: As of 10.5, you can also use `-[NSMenuItem setView:]` to use any kind of NSView in a menu item. For example, sliders, steppers, etc. Don't get carried away with it, but notice how the Help menu in 10.5+ starts with a Spotlight-like search box...